# angular.injector not behaving as imagined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to use angular.injector as a service locator to retrieve a service in the base class from which many controllers are derived. I'm doing this because I don't want to have to modify the constructor signature of dozens of controllers in order to get hold of an instance of my service. I am more than happy to sacrifice having a rogue service like this in order to avoid lots of risky work on my controllers.

My base controller looks like this:

```
module Controllers {
    "use strict";

    export class MyBaseController {
        static $inject = ["$q"];

        protected qService: angular.IQService;
        private myService: Services.MyService;

        constructor($q: angular.IQService) {
            this.qService = $q;

            // falls over on this next line
            this.myService = angular.injector(["myApp"]).get("MyService");
        }

        protected myBehaviour(details: any) {
            this.myService.myServiceMethod(details);
        }
    }
}
```

My service looks like this:

```
module Services {
    "use strict";

    export class MyService {
        static $inject = ["$modal"];

        private modal;
        private modalInstance;

        constructor($modal) {
            this.modal = $modal;
        }

        public myServiceMethod() {
            // do something with $modal
        }
    }
}
```

The error on the line in my controller looks like this:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $animate <- $compile <- $modalStack <- $modal <- ApplicationErrorService
```

Am I misunderstanding the function of injector? Is the problem that I can't create an instance of the service because the service itself has dependencies that cannot be resolved?

Much appreciation of any help on this one.

Comment: As I read it, it looks like you might have a missing dependency on ngAnimate.

Comment: Why dont you just inject `MyService` to the controller, not sure if i understand why you need to get it by creating an injector? Also you could as well just do `constructor(protected qService: angular.IQService) {`

Comment: I can't inject MyService because that would mean modifying all of the derived controllers to pass in a reference to the service.

Comment: @serlingpa That is what "D" stands for in the SOLID principle. And what you are trying to do looks like an anti-pattern.

Comment: Yes I know that. I am using a dependency injection container as a service locator. But as I explained in my post I am quite happy to sacrifice having a rogue service like this in order to avoid lots of risky work on my controllers. Any other comments?

Comment: Makes no sense. Anyways assuming the service is a part of module (or its dependent) which you are running from, you do no need to create an injector instead just get the injector by injecting `$injector`  and do `$injector.get("MyService")` or grab the injector that is already created from the rootElement `angular.element(yourrootelement).injector().get("MyService")`

Answer (score 0):

> Is the problem that I can't create an instance of the service because the service itself has dependencies that cannot be resolved

Yes. Specifically `$rootElement` is not available. This is a tell tale sign that the code is executing *before* angular has been bootstrapped : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

Comment: But the error does not occur until the line I annotated above is hit.